# How to declare a multi-multi- dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

Sounds simple and it probably is.

I have this variable:

```
byte[,,] data = new byte[360,288]
```

And I want 4 for them.

I do not want this though:

```
byte[,,,] data = new byte[360,288,4]
```

I prefer this:

```
byte[,,][] data = new byte[360,288][4]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: This is a special case of jagged arrays.

Comment: @Damian Thanks for the link but it does not solve my question unfortunately.

Comment: @BlueTrin at least I know what to Google now!  Thanks

Comment: Look at my answer I think it is what you need, I inverted the dimensions but you could do it with a nested for if you want to keep the dimensions you have shown in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a special case of jagged arrays, one where one of the jagged dimension is multidimensional.

You should write something like this:

```
        // Initialise 4 arrays of two dimensional arrays
        byte[][,] data = new byte[4][,];
        // Initialise the arrays
        for (var i = data.GetLowerBound(0); i <= data.GetLowerBound(0); ++i)
            data[i] = new byte[360, 258];
```

Of course you can invert the dimensions if you need it.

```
        // Initialise 4 arrays of two dimensional arrays
        byte[,][] data2 = new byte[360,258][];
        // Initialise the arrays
        for (var i = data2.GetLowerBound(0); i <= data2.GetLowerBound(0); ++i)
            for (var j = data2.GetLowerBound(1); j <= data2.GetLowerBound(1); ++j)
                data2[i,j] = new byte[4];
```

Comment: Hi, yes I did a Google search and implemented it.  It matches your answer so thanks!